# Error loading tab created from OSM

Tags: qgis, shapefile, openstreetmap, mapinfo, tab

I downloaded open street map data via Quick OSM in QGIS 3.16. Exporting the data to shapefiles works, but I need them as mapinfo (tab). When I export as tab, the file is saved (Successfully saved vector layer to...), but cannot be loaded:
"CRITICAL    Invalid Data Source : .../GIS/shops1.tab|layername=shops1 is not a valid or recognized data source." The same happens when I export the shp as tab from GRASS GIS and try to import.
Happens both on Windows and Mac. Any hints what can cause this?

Comment: One thing to check is the file size. Is the Shape file close to 2GB? If so, that might make the TAB files run over the 2GB file limit. If you open the Shape file in MapInfo Pro, you can try saving it into the extended tab format that doesn't have the file size limitation

Comment: Do you also have the other parts (.map, .dat)? Could you share test data? What program gives the error?

Comment: Thank you! The shp file is around 40KB, the tab 100MB. 
The error is in QGIS. GRASS GIS does not find a layer for import. 

Link to data (shp and tab - not sure if that is the appropriate way to share data): 
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9e64af55e3a1d13c6f4c3f5ea027896020210823194918/8db1c0211f644727c3ab8334ecac23e320210823195010/521bcb

Comment: I just tried to export only supermarkets (downloaded as supermarkets from OSM) instead of all shops - that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you shared has 200 field, and there must be some export issue from QGIS.

**Workaround**

Export from QGIS to Mapinfo's TAB only selecting some fields.
I tried with the following ones using the `shp` you provided:

[image]

The generated `.tab` file imports flawlessly:

[image]

My guess is that some field names have non-ascii characters: if you need more/all fields, you might need to hunt down which ones cause the problem, and rename it before exporting.

Comment: Indeed - that was the problem. Export with just the required fields worked. Simple - could have figured that out myself I recon. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the problem directly, but a work-around: download from Overpass Turbo as kml (not geojson - same problem as above!), then convert to tab.